# Get unused Nagios both services and commands

Tags: scripting, nagios, cgi

I have a monitoring server, based on Nagios 3.2.3, installed via source code, and using GroundWork Monitor Architect for managing Nagios configurations.

My question is if possible (and how to) get a list of services that are not applying to any host, and a list of commands that are not being used by any service.

Thanks in advance.
Regards.

Comment: Nagios does not allow you to make services that are not attached to any hosts/hostgroups. Perhaps this is a GroundWork question?

Comment: I also use a third party tool to manage Nagios configuration. It also uses a backend Mysql database, like GroundWork. What i usually do for such needs is direclty querying the database with SQL scripts.